# Max-margin loss in Keras/theano

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, theano, loss-function

I want to train a neural network in Keras (with theano as backend) with a max-margin loss function using one negative sample per positive sample:

```
 max(0,1 -pos_score +neg_score)
```

I have a neural network which takes two arguments `i` and `j` and return score `base(i,j)`. For given `i`, I have a positive sample `j` and negative sample `k`. So, I want to compute the following:

```
 max(0, 1 - base(i, j) + base(i, k))
```

At abstract level, my code looks like the following:

```
i = Input(...) # d=100
j = Input(...) # d=300
k = Input(...) # d=300

i_vec = Sequential()
i_vec.add(Dense(20, input_dim=100))
j_vec = Sequential()
j_vec.add(Dense(30, input_dim=300))

base = Sequential()
base.add(Merge([i_vec, j_vec], mode='concat')
# Here goes definition of the base network
base.add(Dense(output_dim=1, bias=False))

pos = base([i, j])
neg = base([i, k])

def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.maximum(0, 1 - y_pred[0] + y_pred[1])

model = Model(input=[i,j,k], output=[pos, neg])
# Shape of I=(1000,100), J and K=(1000,300), XX=(1000,)
model.fit([I, J, K], [XX,XX], nb_epoch=10)
```

Note that the `XX` is useless during the training.

While running the code, I got the following error:

```
ValueError: GpuElemwise. Output dimension mismatch. Output 0 (indices start at 0), working inplace on input 0, has shape[0] == 1, but the output's size on that axis is 32.
Apply node that caused the error: GpuElemwise{Composite{(i0 * (i1 * i2))}}[(0, 0)](GpuElemwise{Composite{Cast{float32}(EQ(i0, i1))}}[(0, 0)].0, GpuElemwise{Composite{(i0 / (i1 * i2))}}[(0, 0)].0, GpuFromHost.0)
Toposort index: 83
Inputs types: [CudaNdarrayType(float32, vector), CudaNdarrayType(float32, (True,)), CudaNdarrayType(float32, vector)]
Inputs shapes: [(1,), (1,), (32,)]
Inputs strides: [(0,), (0,), (1,)]
Inputs values: [CudaNdarray([ 1.]), CudaNdarray([ 1.]), 'not shown']
Outputs clients: [[GpuIncSubtensor{InplaceInc;int64}(GpuIncSubtensor{Inc;int64}.0, GpuElemwise{Composite{(i0 * (i1 * i2))}}[(0, 0)].0, Constant{1}), GpuElemwise{neg,no_inplace}(GpuElemwise{Composite{(i0 * (i1 * i2))}}[(0, 0)].0)]]
```

I think the problem is in the computation of the loss function.

Note: I have tried with the `XX` as raw vector and column vector. But, the error remains same.

Solution for the same problem with TensorFlow as backend is available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37689632/max-margin-loss-in-tensorflow) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38270166/tensorflow-max-margin-loss-training).

---

#### Edit 1:

Changing the loss function as below works (I mean it works without any error). But, neither I know why nor I know about the correctness of the new code.

```
def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.sum(K.maximum(0, 1 - y_pred[0] + y_pred[1]))
```

Comment: it minimizes the mean (sum is scaled mean) of your maximum loss.  It is mean of max, not max of max.  you might think about K.maximum(K.maximum(…))

Comment: For a (mini) batch optimization in ML, it is common practice to optimize the average loss. The average is over loss values for each example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like `K.maximum(0, 1 - y_pred[0] + y_pred[1])` does not give you a *scalar* loss value, but rather the error per sample. You need to average the loss for the entire minibatch. Thus, using `K.sum` reduce the per-sample loss to a per-minibatch scalar loss. I suppose it would be more accurate to use `mean` instead of `sum` (in case you decide to change batch size).

Comment: Got it, @shai. But, will it work as expected or not? I'm asking about the correctness of the code.